# trait to check function accepts certain parameters but not return type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I'm trying to write a type trait in c++11 (msvc2013) that will allow me to check that a function type takes certain parameters. I *don't* want it to check the return type. I think the idea is basically equivalent to `std::is_callable`, but I'm interested in knowing what's wrong with my approach, in addition to how to actually solve the problem.

my implementation:

```
namespace traits
{
    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct is_write_function_impl
        {
            const char* c = nullptr;
            size_t l = 0;

            template<typename U>
            static auto test(U*)->decltype(declval<U>()(c, l), std::true_type);
            template<typename U>
            static auto test(...)->std::false_type;

            using type = decltype(test<T>(0));
        };
    }

    template <typename T>
    struct is_write_function : detail::is_write_function_impl<T>::type {};
}
```

my test case:

```
std::ofstream os;
auto valid = std::bind(&std::ofstream::write, &os, 
    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

// want this to be 'true' but get 'false'
std::cout << traits::is_write_function<decltype(valid)>::value;
```

Comment: I heard that VS 2013 does not support expression SFINAE, so it might be impossible to implement this in VS 2013.

Comment: @cpplearner not sure if it's apples and oranges, but I use this basic pattern to check static member functions of classes all the time in 2013. I'm just having trouble adapting it to function objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a few issues, which would be detected by a better compiler ;) - but if you fix them, your code will work with VS 2013 (tested with 12.0.31101.00 Update 4):

```
static auto test(U*)->decltype(declval<U>()(c, l), std::true_type);
                               #1           #2     #3
```

1. This should be `std::declval`.
2. You can't refer to non-`static` data members in the declaration of a `static` member function, even within a non-deduced context. This should be `(std::declval<char const*>(), std::declval<std::size_t>())`.
3. `std::true_type` is a type, and `decltype` is an expression context. Write `std::true_type{}`.

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7ccf1ca2ba43d38).

Comment: who needs a better compiler with such quality help? :)